# Why does my Google search results end up on my index page?

Tags: search, joomla, seo, joomla-sef-urls

I have a webpage and my google search results are linked to the index page, even though the title and the description of the result are correct the url isn't. 
How can I address that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 301 redirect or put homepage url as canonical to resolve this issue.

**Canonical tag for index page:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.domain.com/" />
```

If I understand something different than please explain ..

Comment: I don't want to redirect my homepage I want my Google search results to show at the appropriate page of my site not the homepage only.

Comment: I have eg my index page "mysite.com/index.php". Also,  I have my product page "mysite.com/awesomeproduct". When someone searches on the Google search engine with the query "awesome product"  my index page is listed along with its link  and page title BUT this  description is my product's description. When the user clicks on the search result is redirected to the index page not the  product page.